# Object of type [class java.util.Properties] available at JNDI location [comp/env/test] is not assignable to [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, glassfish, jndi

I need to connect Spring MVC app to oracle database throw Glassfish server.

This is my MVCconfiguration.java

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {

    //Option 1 it works
    //DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    //dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    //dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xx.xx:1521:dtest");
    //dataSource.setUsername("user");
    //dataSource.setPassword("pass");    

    //Option 2 didn't work
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean(); 
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    try {
    dataSource = jndi.lookup("comp/env/test", DataSource.class);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
    }


    //Option 3 didn't work
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("comp/env/test");              

    return dataSource;        

}
```

In glassfish there is a jdbc resource and jndi custom resources

[image: jndi]

[image: jdbc resources]

But when I deploy war file I got this error:

[image: Error]

> Object of type [class java.util.Properties] available at JNDI location [comp/env/test] is not assignable to [javax.sql.DataSource].

Comment: According to your first screenshot `comp/env/test` **is** a properties object. In other words, you can't use it as a data source. Right now you have only defined the pool, but you also need to define a JDBC resource which **uses** that pool, and then reference it as `comp/env/jdbc/<resourcename>`.

Answer (score 0):

JNDI custom resource is a **java.util.properties** 
JDBC resource is related to the JDBC connection pool (could be **javax.sql.datasource**)

Just remove JNDI custom resource, and use JDBC resource instead